# Uploading File to GCS - Metadata part is too large

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

We are trying to upload files to GCS using signed urls. The client asks for a signed url to upload a file and our server sends a signed url to the client. The client then uploads the file using that signed url. This is working fine for cases where file size < 2MB. But the limit for the object size in GCS is 5TB.

Below is the code used to generate the signed url

```py
blob = Blob.from_string(filepath, client=gcp_storage_client)
blob.generate_signed_url(version="v4", expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=5), method="POST")
```

We are getting the response "Metadata part is too large". But we are not adding any metadata to the file. Please check the screenshot from Postman below.

What am I doing wrong here? and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCS has several mechanisms to upload objects. The one you're using is the HTML form "POST object" mechanism. POST uploads do not support signed URLs. They use signed [policy documents](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document) instead, which are a bit more complicated but have some extra capabilities.

If your client is using not a human being using an HTML form, I suggest using [PUT object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-upload) for uploads. It's simpler, and it supports signed URLs. It would look like this:

```
PUT /OBJECT_NAME??X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=whatnot HTTP/1.1
Host: BUCKET_NAME.storage.googleapis.com
Date: DATE
Content-Length: FILE_LENGTH
Content-Type: FILE_MIME_TYPE
Content-MD5: MD5_DIGEST
x-goog-storage-class: DESIRED_STORAGE_CLASS

<file goes here>
```

Comment: In addition to Brandon's correct answer, you must specify any HTTP headers that the client will use in the HTTP PUT, such as **content-type**, when signing the URL.

Comment: @Brandon But I am able to successfully upload files of less than 2mb using HTML form Post object mechanism using a signed url.

Comment: Also, https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html I am not able to find about policy documents in the documentation here.

Comment: It's `Bucket.generate_upload_policy`: https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html?highlight=policy#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.generate_upload_policy